# python regex replace only part of NOT match

Tags: python, regex

I have many html codes which have `<pre> python code </pre>`, just like following

**html code:**

```
<pre class="c1">
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>

python tutorial ...python regex<br>

<pre class="c2">
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>
```

I regard `regex` as a keyword, and replace it to a link: `<a href="link-to-regex">regex</a>`,but I don't want to replace contents in label `<pre>`

**output:**

```
<pre class="c1">
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>

python tutorial ...python <a href="link-to-regex">regex</a><br>

<pre class="c2">
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>
```

I do it use placeholders

```
pre_list = re.compile(r'(<pre>.+?</pre>)').findall(html_code)

# use CODE_PLACEHODER to protect code sources
for index,code in enumerate(pre_list):
    html_code = html_code.replace(code, 'CODE_PLACEHOLDER_{}'.format(index))

# replace the html content here
html_code = html_code.replace('regex', '<a href="link-to-regex">regex</a>')

for index,code in enumerate(pre_list):
    html_code = html_code.replace('CODE_PLACEHOLDER_{}'.format(index), code)
    enter code here
```

Better method to do this?

Comment: What's your expected output? Is this a html file?

Comment: It doesn't matter, just how to 'protect' the content in <pre> and replace others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  positive lookaround assertions to match the string `regex` which is not present inside the `<pre>` tag. And don't forget to enable DOTALL modifier.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """<pre>
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>

python tutorial ...python regex<br>
<pre>
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>"""
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?s)regex(?!(?:(?!<\/?pre[^<>]*>).)*<\/pre>)', r'<a href="link-to-regex">regex</a>', s)
>>> print m
<pre>
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>

python tutorial ...python <a href="link-to-regex">regex</a><br>
<pre>
# regex usage
import re
re.findall(r'abc','abcde')
</pre>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/9)

Comment: It doesn't work well if have more `<pre>` in html code:http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/4

Comment: @WeizhongTu but in your example, you put the ending pre tag as `<pre>`

Comment: But in fact, it is more difficult, every <pre> has a class, and they are may be different, http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/6

Comment: it's soo easy see http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/7 , use `[^<>]*` instead of `.*` in opening pre tag.

Comment: even better to use this `regex(?!(?:(?!<\/?pre[^<>]*>).)*<\/pre>)`

Answer (score 0):

```
regex(?=(?:((?!<pre[^>]*>|<\/pre>).)*<pre[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/pre>).)*<\/pre>)*(?:(?!<pre[^>]*>|<\/pre>).)*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/8

Comment: When I add the sentence `HTML tutoial: about <code><pre></code>`, it doesn't work

Comment: But you didn't have `<code><pre></code>` in your question, so how can you expect people to know that the regex has to deal with stuff like that?? Perhaps you should be using a proper HTML / XML parser like lxml, rather than going through the frustration of trying to do this with regexes.